# Insert a XML in a Dictionary using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dictionary

I have this XML file:

```
<RootNode>
    <Node1>Value1</Node1>
    <Node2>Value2</Node2>
    <Node3>Value3</Node3>
    <Node4>
        <SubNode1>SubValue1</SubNode1>
        <SubNode2>SubValue2</SubNode2>
        <SubNode3>SubValue3</SubNode3>
        <SubNode4>SubValue4</SubNode4>
    </Node4>
    <Node4>
        <SubNode1>SubValue1</SubNode1>
        <SubNode2>SubValue2</SubNode2>
        <SubNode3>SubValue3</SubNode3>
        <SubNode4>SubValue4</SubNode4>
    </Node4>
</RootNode>
```

I have more Nodes like "Node4". I want to save this items in a dictionary with LINQ but I have not been able to do.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I only try this (sorry for the code, but I'm new in LINQ, and this code only try to insert Nodes 4 and their SubNodes):

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
Dictionary<string, List<string>> datas = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

foreach (XElement item in xDocument.Root.Elements().Where(x => x.Elements().Count() > 0))
{
    datas.Add(item.Name.LocalName, item.Elements("SubNode1").Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
}
```

but this return at second iteration an error of duplicate key. It's normal because the others Node4 also called Node4.

Comment: What would be your dictionary key if subnote1 is the value? I would more see a List in this than a dictionary

Comment: What do you exactly want to store in your dictionary?

Comment: I want to insert all nodes with their values, and for the Nodes 4 I want to insert, in the same dictionary, as key SubNode1 value and as values a List<string> of the rest of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it like below:

```
var datas = xDocument.Root.Elements()
                .Select(
                    e => e.Descendants().Count() > 0?
                    new { 
                        key = e.Descendants().Single(x => x.Name.LocalName == "SubNode1").Value,
                        value =  e.Descendants().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
                        }:
                    new { 
                        key = e.Name.LocalName, 
                        value = new List<string>(){ e.Value } 
                        }
                ).ToDictionary( k => k.key, v => v.value );
```

Comment: And why? Code without explanation isn't very helpful. It might help the OP in this case, but not passing-by Googlers.

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman: Explanation: filtering -> selection -> projection -> conversion

Comment: Hi!, With this code I have problems of key duplicated, because Node4, in all of their repetitions is called "Node4". I'm going to edit the main message for give you a better information.

Comment: @user3535054: You can't have two items under same key inside Dictionary. Key must be unique. Is another collection type for storing result acceptable?

Comment: The key for the Nodes4 must be the "SubValue1" of each "Node4". I edited the first message, because of I had wrong values.

Comment: OK - I've updated solution according your requirements changes